# How can I add hyperparameters while prompting a model using Databricks Serving Endpoints?

Tags: python-requests, databricks, huggingface-transformers, mlflow, large-language-model

I am currently using the following code, adapted from this [page](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/model-serving/score-model-serving-endpoints.html#language-python), to query an LLM model through a Databricks endpoint:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

model_uri = $MODEL_URI
databricks_api_token = $TOKEN

def create_tf_serving_json(data):
  return {'inputs': {name: data[name].tolist() for name in data.keys()} if isinstance(data, dict) else data.tolist()}

def score_model(model_uri, databricks_token, data):
  headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {databricks_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
  data_json = json.dumps({'dataframe_records': data.to_dict(orient='records')}) if isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame) else create_tf_serving_json(data)
  response = requests.request(method='POST', headers=headers, url=model_uri, json=data_json)
  if response.status_code != 200:
      raise Exception(f"Request failed with status {response.status_code}, {response.text}")
  return response.json()

text = 'Hello, my name is'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/pythia-160m-deduped")
text_ids = tokenizer.encode(text, return_tensors = 'pt')
# data = np.asarray([[n, n, n]])
output = str(score_model(model_uri, databricks_api_token, text_ids))
print(output[16:-1])
```

I am trying to figure out how to change the hyperparameters related to generation, such as top_p, temperature, number of responses, number of min/max tokens generated, etc. So far, I have found absolutely zero documentation on how to do this. Is it just not possible? Is there some way to do it on the MLFlow side, while registering the model?